# How to create custom levels in log4r via yaml

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, yaml, log4r

I have a Rails 4.1 app using log4r 1.1.10 configured via yaml and everything works fine. Now I just want to add a custom level. So at the top of my yaml file I added seven lines after `log4r_config`:

```
log4r_config:
  pre_config:
    custom_levels:
      - INFO
      - WARN
      - ERROR
      - SERIOUS
      - FATAL
  # define all loggers ...
  loggers:
```

The relevant part of my application.rb looks like:

```
require 'log4r'
require 'log4r/yamlconfigurator'
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),"../lib/rollable_file_outputter.rb")
include Log4r
log4r_config = YAML.load_file(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),"log4r.yml"))
YamlConfigurator.decode_yaml( log4r_config['log4r_config'] )
```

But when I launch the app now I get

```
ArgumentError: Log level must be in 0..7
/opt/thermyos.com/server/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/log4r-1.1.10/lib/log4r/yamlconfigurator.rb:189:in `decode_logger_common'
/opt/thermyos.com/server/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/log4r-1.1.10/lib/log4r/yamlconfigurator.rb:175:in `decode_logger'
/opt/thermyos.com/server/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/log4r-1.1.10/lib/log4r/yamlconfigurator.rb:69:in `block in decode_yaml'
/opt/thermyos.com/server/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/log4r-1.1.10/lib/log4r/yamlconfigurator.rb:69:in `each'
/opt/thermyos.com/server/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/log4r-1.1.10/lib/log4r/yamlconfigurator.rb:69:in `decode_yaml'
/opt/thermyos.com/server/releases/20141209152838/config/application.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
```

What's the right way to define custom log4r levels in yaml?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is *never leave out the DEBUG level*. It was just an oversight on my part. Since Log4r uses the debug level to write debug messages, leaving it out is very bad.

Comment: It seems that Log4r itself uses an [internal_log](https://github.com/colbygk/log4r/blob/master/lib/log4r/staticlogger.rb#L43) method to write debug messages. Custom levels works fine in [my test cases](https://github.com/bestmike007/log4rails/blob/master/spec/xml_config_spec.rb#L26). Are you replacing Rails logger with Log4r?

Comment: I am indeed replacing the Rails logger with Log4r. Custom levels worked fine for me once I included DEBUG. I don't have my notes or even my original application.rb file, but it's entirely possible that the reference to DEBUG came from my own log4r.yml file.

Comment: If you had replaced Rails logger with Log4r in development mode, an error should have occurred using Rails 4.1 when the Rack is trying to access `Rails.logger.format`. I recently created a new fork named [log4rails](http://bestmike007.com/log4rails/) to make log4r much more compatible to rails, especially for latest rails.